# How do I set a different number of port using Square's okHttp?

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm trying to connect [okHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) with a web service but with different port, for example, 10000. My idea to stub the responses with a proxy during the unit tests. Neverthless, there is not enough documentation to make it with this library. As a matter of fact, my implementation is:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

For example, with other libraries such as [loopj](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/), this feature is possible:

```
httpClient.setProxy("localhost", 10000);
```

I'm using this version: `com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I'm trying to connect okHttp with a web service but with different port, for example, 10000

Put the port in the URL that you supply to `Request.Builder`:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("http://publicobject.com:10000/helloworld.txt")
    .build();
```

> My idea to stub the responses with a proxy during the unit tests.

Use a different URL for the tests than you do in production.

Comment: You can also set the port building the URL with the ''HttpUrl.Builder" http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/HttpUrl.Builder.html#port-int-

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you. I tried your solution and It worked. For tests, I used Mockwebserver, using it like a proxy server, pointing the url out as "http://localhost:10000" instead of the real url for the api.

Comment: Probably I'm missing something, but I don't get why okHttp can't take hostname and port from WiFi settings, when connection through a proxy is required.

Comment: Use a different URL for the tests than you do in production. hahahah

Comment: I used his solution, it didn't work for me. It was using port 80 by default.

So, I used followed this way. `new HttpUrl.Builder().scheme(this.scheme).host(this.host).port(this.port).build().toString()`

And then I added the path to the URL and point to be noted that the builder sets `/` in the end. so remote the forward slash from the path if you add to this.